# How to add a background color on UITextView link attributes in ios?

Tags: ios, objective-c, uitextview

I have an UITextView and It contains 2 links. I set the font color using,

```
- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath {

    static NSString *CellIdentifier = @"moduleCell";

    CustomerTableViewCell *cell = (CustomerTableViewCell*)[tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier: CellIdentifier];

    if (cell == nil) {

        NSArray *nib = [[NSBundle mainBundle] loadNibNamed:@"CustomerTableViewCell" owner:self options:nil];
        cell = [nib objectAtIndex:0];

        cell.backgroundColor = [UIColor clearColor];
        cell.selectedBackgroundView = [[UIImageView alloc] initWithImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@""]];
        cell.selectionStyle = UITableViewCellSelectionStyleNone;

        [cell setSeparatorInset:UIEdgeInsetsZero];
        cell.appContext = self.appContext;

        currentCustomer = [customersArr objectAtIndex:indexPath.row-1];
        [cell setCellDetails:customersArr WithIndex:row-1 withParentView:self];

        cell.postedText.linkTextAttributes= @{NSBackgroundColorAttributeName: [UIColor whiteColor], NSForegroundColorAttributeName: [UIColor blackColor]};
    }
    return cell;

}
```

This change the font color. Then I tried to change the background color of it using `NSBackgroundColorAttributeName` But it doesn't change the background color of the link.
I need to change the link like,

[image]

Can anyone help me on this?

Comment: how you are trying `NSBackgroundColorAttributeName ` please show full code

Comment: updated the question. :

Comment: ok and after that statement you are writing any other statement for changing `postedText` to change other UIs.

Comment: Nope. there are no UI changes then.

Comment: as i know your going right way. please check once after changing order of forground and background color changing. Or changes like bellow answers are also right. Using set attributes to String not textView.

Comment: can you give a little demonstration?

Comment: Provide your code, that works on textViews in my projects.

Comment: Code edited on question.